# Google Maps MarkerClusterer not showing any default images

Tags: google-maps, markerclusterer

I'm adding javascript code snippet to my Wordpress post (Hosted by a 3rd Party). I managed to create an array of Markers, and had them added to the MarkerClusterer and Map. The cluster shows up but as a broken image link and a number.

How do I access the MarkerClusterer default images? I followed the instructions from https://github.com/googlemaps/js-markerclusterer/blob/main/README.md

I'm not sure how to use npm with the 3rd party hosting. I don't use a database with my website. I'm calling src="https://unpkg.com/@googlemaps/markerclusterer/dist/index.min.js" to import MarkerClusterer

```
<div id="gmap" style="width:100%;height:400px;"></div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@googlemaps/markerclusterer/dist/index.min.js"</script>
```

```
    var mymap;
var markers = [];
function initMap() {
    var centerpoint = { lat: 38.5, lng: -98 }; //centered around Kansas
    mymap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('gmap'), {
        zoom: 4,
        center: centerpoint
    });
}

/** fetching a cvs file on the server side with a list of locations */
fetch("https://mywebsite.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/03/stores.csv")
  .then(
    function(response) {
      if (response.status !== 200) {
        console.log('Looks like there was a problem. Status Code: ' +
          response.status);
        return;
      }  

      // Examine the text in the response
      response.text().then(function(data) {
        count = 0;
        console.log("fetch called successfully");
        initMap();
        processCSV(data);
      });
    }
  )
  .catch(function(err) {
    console.log('Fetch Error :-S', err);
  });

function processCSV(allData){
      const rows = allData.split('\n');
      var storename, storephone, storeaddress, storelat, storelng;
  
      for(let i=0; i<rows.length; i++){
        var line = rows[i];
        storename = line.split(",")[1];
        storephone = line.split(",")[3];
        storeaddress = String(line.split(",")[2]);
        storeaddress = replaceAll(storeaddress, "^", ",");
        storelat = line.split(",")[4];
        storelng = line.split(",")[5];
        createMarker(storename, storephone, storeaddress, storelat, storelng);
      }
      createCluster();
}
function replaceAll(string, search, replace) {
  return string.split(search).join(replace);
}
function createCluster(){
    var mcluster =new MarkerClusterer( mymap , markers);
   
 }
function createMarker(name, phone, address, latstr, lngstr) {
 var contentString = "<b>" + name + "</b><br><br><i>" + phone + "</i><br><br>" + address;
 var latLng = { lat: Number(latstr) , lng: Number(lngstr)};

 var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: contentString,
  });
 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
     position: latLng,
     map: mymap,
     title: name
 });
markers.push(marker);
console.log("added marker to map" + name);
  marker.addListener("click", () => {
    infowindow.open({
      anchor: marker,
      map: mymap,
      shouldFocus: false,
    });
  });    
}
```

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=<PRIVATEKEY>;callback=initMap"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

The version of `MarkerClusterer` you are using doesn't require `ClusterIcons` (unless you want to change them), they default to SVG icons coded inline.

When I run the posted code I get a javascript error: `Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: MarkerClusterer is not defined`.

That is because according to [the documentation](https://github.com/googlemaps/js-markerclusterer/blob/main/README.md) when you include the library the way you are (`<script src="https://unpkg.com/@googlemaps/markerclusterer/dist/index.min.js"></script>`), the constructor for the MarkerClusterer is accessed as:

> **When adding via unpkg**, the `MarkerClusterer` can be accessed at `markerClusterer.MarkerClusterer`.

Changing that, makes the clusters appear.

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/1gu6fcL3/2/)

[image: screenshot showing cluster]

**code snippet:**

```js
var mymap;
var markers = [];

function initMap() {
  var centerpoint = {
    lat: 40.7127753,
    lng: -74.0059728
  }; //centered around New York City
  mymap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('gmap'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: centerpoint
  });
  processCSV(data);
}
var data = '"","New York","New York^ NY","516-555-5555",40.7127753, -74.0059728\n"","Newark","Newark^ NJ","201-555-5555",40.735657, -74.1723667';

function processCSV(allData) {
  console.log(allData);
  const rows = allData.split('\n');
  var storename, storephone, storeaddress, storelat, storelng;

  for (let i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    var line = rows[i];
    storename = line.split(",")[1];
    storephone = line.split(",")[3];
    storeaddress = String(line.split(",")[2]);
    storeaddress = replaceAll(storeaddress, "^", ",");
    storelat = line.split(",")[4];
    storelng = line.split(",")[5];
    createMarker(storename, storephone, storeaddress, storelat, storelng);
  }
  createCluster();
}

function replaceAll(string, search, replace) {
  return string.split(search).join(replace);
}

function createCluster() {
  var mcluster = new markerClusterer.MarkerClusterer({
    map: mymap,
    markers: markers
  });
}

function createMarker(name, phone, address, latstr, lngstr) {
  var contentString = "<b>" + name + "</b><br><br><i>" + phone + "</i><br><br>" + address;
  var latLng = {
    lat: Number(latstr),
    lng: Number(lngstr)
  };

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: contentString,
  });
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latLng,
    map: mymap,
    title: name
  });
  markers.push(marker);
  console.log("added marker to map" + name);
  marker.addListener("click", () => {
    infowindow.open({
      anchor: marker,
      map: mymap,
      shouldFocus: false,
    });
  });
}
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */

#gmap {
  height: 100%;
}


/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Simple Map</title>
  <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>
  <!-- jsFiddle will insert css and js -->
</head>

<body>
  <div id="gmap"></div>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/@googlemaps/markerclusterer/dist/index.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Async script executes immediately and must be after any DOM elements used in callback. -->
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap&v=weekly&channel=2" async></script>
</body>
</html>
```